# Stuck trying to organize a column's data post-concatenation

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to pull data from a SQLite table that looks like this:

```
IP                 PORT        PROTOCOL
-------------------------------------------
192.168.50.106     0           TCP
192.168.50.106     0           TCP
192.168.50.106     68          UDP
192.168.50.106     53          TCP
192.168.50.106     53          TCP

192.168.50.109     0           TCP
192.168.50.109     0           TCP
192.168.50.109     53          UDP
192.168.50.109     445         TCP
192.168.50.109     445         TCP
192.168.50.109     139         TCP
```

Now, using the command:

```
SELECT IP, GROUP_CONCAT(Port, ',') From PortData WHERE Protocol = 'TCP' GROUP BY Ip ORDER BY IP ASC
```

I get:

```
IP                    PORT
--------------------------------------
192.168.50.106        0,0,53,53
192.168.50.109        0,0,445,445,139
```

Which is really close to what I need! I just need the "Port" column to only display distinct port values, and have those ordered by ascending port number. I'm pretty stumped on how to organize that second column's data after it has been concatenated.

Here's what I'm trying to get the output to look like if you'd like an example:

```
IP                    PORT
--------------------------------------
192.168.50.106        0,53
192.168.50.109        0,139,445
```

Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't organize formatted data after, rather **before** by having a preliminary query eliminate the duplicates and generate the correct order.  Do this either as a subquery or a common table expression (CTE) (i.e. WITH clause).

(Trying to sort and eliminate duplicates afterward would essentially require re-parsing the string, putting it in a table, sorting and removing duplicates, then putting it back in a list. You'd just be going full circle. Or if not in the database, one would have to do it using the host language, but it require the same overall steps.)

```
WITH prepped AS (
     SELECT IP, Port From PortData 
     WHERE Protocol = 'TCP' 
     GROUP BY IP, Port 
     ORDER BY IP, Port
)
SELECT IP, GROUP_CONCAT(Port, ',') 
FROM prepped 
GROUP BY Ip 
ORDER BY IP ASC
```